# How can I display image child category in parent

Tags: categories

This code work perfect, but I want to show **child image** too. I use ACF plugin.

Can you help me please?

```php
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
    'parent'     => $term->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

if ( $children ) {
    foreach( $children as $subcat ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">'.'<span> مقالات دسته</span>' . $subcat->name . ' </a>'.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
 <?php

                $term = get_queried_object();
                $children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
                    'parent'    => $term->term_id,

                    'hide_empty' => false
                ) );

                if ( $children ) {
                    foreach( $children as $subcat ) {

                                $size = "thumbnail";
                                echo ' <div class=" cat-box  ">';
                                $image = get_field('image', 'category_' . $subcat->term_id);
                                echo '<img src="' . $image . '" />';

                                echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . '<span> مقالات دسته</span>' . $subcat->name . ' </a>' . '</div>';

                                '</div>';


                            }
                            }
                ?>
```